# How to deploy Gatsby Shopify store to Netlify?

Tags: reactjs, shopify, gatsby

Hi I recently made a Gatsby E-commerce store using Shopify api. It's not a real business however I would like to host the site on Netlify as a portfolio project.
I have "successfully" deployed on netlify however when you go on the domain the site shows for a second before going blank.
I notice the Gatsby Shopify starter is deployed successfully.
Thanks.

[Link to Site on Netlify.](https://nifty-montalcini-2510f8.netlify.com/)

Comment: Could you send us the url maybe ?

Comment: Of course I should of posted it in the question! https://nifty-montalcini-2510f8.netlify.com/